# As an individual, how to send frozen food to someone else in France?

Tags: food, temperature, food-safety

As a gift for Christmas, I would like to offer regional frozen food to my family living 900km away (but still in France) which can only be bought in my region as it is hard to find it elsewhere (we stopped eating those things for a while for this very reason as an extensive cooking process is required otherwise).
In details, it is no longer sold in retail and has to be bought directly to a local farm.

The problem is all the parcel services I found which offer refrigerated sending are for companies only. A similar thing can be said about next day delivery services where perishable food is part of unauthorized goods.
As an apprentice aged above 18, I have no day off besides sundays, even for Christmas. So I can t come personally.

As an individual, how to send the food while ensuring it doesn t melt?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I would assume that you are capable of packaging the food in a way that it will withstand ambient temperature for the required time? E.g. insulated, with dry ice or sufficient ice packs? Or are you dead set on a refrigerated truck as means of transport? In that case, you are close to leaving Lifehacks territory. Just saying.

Comment: I can’t comment on the downvote, but maybe give you a hint, also based on your other questions? While you are describing the problem in detail (good), you seem to be set on a specific range of solutions when posting the question and tend to emphasize that in subsequent comments. The whole purpose of this site is to encourage out-of-the-box thinking and finding creative solutions for problems. You may want to check whether you’re tripping over an X-Y problem occasionally, and I would also encourage you to show a bit more appreciation for the user’s effort, even if they don’t fit 100%.

Comment: @Stephie this is about excluding solutions that don’t work for me. It would require a large cool box with several Kg of ice packs, so while acceptable, I would prefer something on purpose (maybe there’s a service accepting individuals I missed ?).

Answer (score 1):

Sending food over big distances can be a dangerous game. If the food "deteriorates" during transport, it might damage the health, or even cause death. That is why companies are not happy to get involved. And trucks with refrigeration are too expensive for an individual wishing to deliver 1-2 kg of something.

You can try to NOT declare the content and ship the thing by normal means. You make sure that:

- you pack several of those (usually) blue "penguins" used for refrigeration with your parcel;
- put everything in some bag and seal that bag in a way that nothing will spill outside in case of something melting;
- put everything in a thermally-insulated box; I occasionally saw polystirene boxes for sale exactly for storing / shipping hot or cold things;
- pray that nobody catches you delivering unapproved goods;
- pray that the food does not get altered during the transportation.

---

It might actually be easier to just send the recipe for that magic food, and the recipient will cook it. Everything will be fresh, and there is no danger to eat spoiled food.

Comment: This is for Christmas. I have no problem paying an overly large ticket for shipping, I m meaning trucks with refrigeration. The problem is finding a service which accepts sendings by an individual. About not declaring, I was caught trying to send gasoline in 2018 and it almost sent me to the police station. I still fill the pain of the 6 year ban and prefer to not try again.

Comment: Not to say that one day outside the freezer, it will definitely melt.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if this works in France, but it (sometimes) works in Canada where I live.  A fairly inexpensive and decently fast way to send small packages is as cargo on a passenger plane. The only drawback is that the recipient has to go to the airport to pick it up.  I have found it to be cheaper, and generally faster, than parcel delivery services on the odd occasion I’ve sent packages by passenger plane. The regulations and options no doubt vary from one airline and jurisdiction to another but it’s worth asking some local airlines.

One other thing: you should pack the food with a temperature recording device so you can verify that the temperature stayed low enough for the whole trip. Alternatively if you’re absolutely sure the temperature can only go in one direction (not guaranteed in winter, I would say) then the recipient should measure the temperature as soon as the package is received.

Comment: Problem, is as explained in the question, I have to time off job wise to come and return.

Comment: @user2284570 You do realize that this post doesn’t imply that *you* fly personally, but just bring your parcel to the airport and it travels with the rest of the luggage? My company does that occasionally and it’s often better/faster than regular courier services on the road.

Comment: I take offense at being called stupid for a service that’s being offered by many passenger airlines and used both by individuals and even by large companies to ship e.g. urgent prototypes. The goods are not accompanied by a passenger and of course not delivered via the bag reel. If you don’t know about something and two users mention it here, it may be an indicator that simply because you haven’t heard about something, it doesn’t mean it doesn’t exist.

Comment: @Stephie it wasn’t about you directly but the idea, and yes I was talking about the luggage not being pickable without the boarding pass. Not the bag.

Answer (score 0):

The German railroad company offers express parcel delivery using the regular passenger train services. You book the “ride”, drop off the package at a station near you and the recipient can pick it up at a selected station. Considering that the ICE can go up to 300km/h, you can’t get much better. Properly insulated and with a few cool packages, food safety should be fine. They explicitly accept biological samples and dry ice, so food shouldn’t be an issue.

As the service includes international destinations, Paris amongst them, I’d check your train service for a similar service.

Comment: The problem is it s Frankreich to Frankreich so where the the service is unavailable. More exactly Quimper Toulon.

Comment: I was not claiming that the services associated with the German rail company DB cover the French market, but that there’s a possibility that SNCF has a similar offer. My French is too rusty to do a detailed research.

Comment: The ꜱɴᴄꜰ doesn’t have a similar offer.

Answer (score 0):

Contact a ride share service (judging from your previous posts you are familiar with them) and book a ride to your destination. Then contact the driver and negotiate with them that instead of you a parcel will ride with them. It may need a few tries and you will probably have to allow them to check the parcel before loading it up, but you should be able to find a friendly traveller willing to help you out. Make sure they have a contact number at the destination and that someone can receive the parcel and promptly transfer the food to the freezer again.

Once you have your mode of transportation secured, focus on finding a safe packaging. I would recommend a good cooler and either dry ice or plenty of ice packs. It should probably be cold enough to keep for two days, that’s going to need a lot of thermal mass and excellent insulation. The folks at Outdoor SE probably have a few more pointers on how to achieve that.

Comment: There are parcel sharing services instead of more general ride services. But if your target doesn’t pass by Paris at All or is very long, you won’t find anyone for months.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not detail if the food in question is/was an animal/a fruit/a meal you prepare by your own, or if it is a commercial product.

If it is for the later and since it is possible to send someone a bouquet of flowers across the nation (e.g., interflora), why shouldn't something similar possible to arrange e.g., with good old [*Picard Surgelés*](https://www.picard.fr/picard-a-votre-service/services/) (since you mention France) with their delivery à domicile?

Comment: The question details it’s a commercial meal prepared by the farm directly. Unfortunately, concerning the goods sold by Picard for this item, they aren’t made in France and are well known for their high lead ratios because of the difference of standards. That dedicated farm doesn’t ship their goods nor does sell them in retails. (they say it isn’t profitable for them).